# Angular build project

Tags: angular

I have an Angular project. I am trying to build it by using "ng build".

But I have this error :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss- 
loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref- 
-8-3!./src/app/assets/sass/main.scss
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: 
/...node_modules/bootstrap- 
sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_glyphicons.scss:19:9: Can't resolve 
'font-path(%22~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons- 
halflings-regular.svg' in '...src/app/assets/sass'
```

I overrided $icon_file_path value : `~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/`

But seems that he can't resolve the path. I tried also to use the default one, I had same issue. Tried to put the complete path, same again.

This is my configuration of ng :

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 6.6.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 4.4.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.3.4
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the reason is in your imports of font path.

Try using import from asset folder instead of somewhere else

```
assets/fonts/bootstrap
assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
```

Also try to import everything static content from assets folder including images/fonts etc

Comment: thanks. i tried that before but File is not found or unreadable

Comment: where you are using these files/content ?

Comment: they are used in bootstrap-saas module in Glyphicons scss file :

it use $icon_file_path variable to retrieve font files.

Comment: Then path should be from `assets` folder , it should work then